# Can we compose/receive audio messages with CarPlay?

Tags: ios, swift, chat, messaging, carplay

We are working on a app that has feature of audio messaging. Now we are planning to start integrating it with carPlay.

Is it possible with Messaging and Voip that we can send/receive audio messaging with CarPlay?

If yes, can anyone suggest some useful links or demos.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you need to use Siri with Messaging:

> The CarPlay framework is for use by navigation apps only. If you want to add CarPlay support to your audio app, use MPPlayableContentManager. For messaging apps, use SiriKit’s Messaging-related intents to support reading and sending messages in CarPlay through Siri. For VoIP calling apps, use CallKit with SiriKit’s VoIP Calling-related intents to make and answer audio calls on a CarPlay system.

If you use other "reader" I think you have to get an access for CarPlay from Apple. Contact with Apple to get an CarPlay entitlement (https://developer.apple.com//contact/carplay/). Then build your CarPlay interface, plug in to a car and just play audio using "regular" app's code.

Comment: But here I need to compose a audio message from carplay, I see WhatsApp doing this but they are doing speech to text, but I need to send audio file as it is to the other end. Is that possible with VOIP?